# JTwitter VerifyError in Android pre-2.0

Tags: android, jtwitter

I'm attempting to integrate JTwitter into an Android application, and I have been completely successful up until the point where I decided to regression test on older Android versions.  In Android 2.x my code works great, but in Android 1.5/1.6 Dalvik throws a VerifyError on the following line:

```
OAuthSignpostClient oauthClient
        = new OAuthSignpostClient(KEY_TWITTER, SECRET_TWITTER, "oob");
```

and provides this logcat output and stack trace:

```
Could not find method javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog, referenced from method winterwell.jtwitter.OAuthSignpostClient.askUser
VFY: unable to resolve static method 1703: Ljavax/swing/JOptionPane;.showInputDialog (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
VFY:  rejected Lwinterwell/jtwitter/OAuthSignpostClient;.askUser (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
Verifier rejected class Lwinterwell/jtwitter/OAuthSignpostClient;
Shutting down VM
threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.VerifyError: winterwell.jtwitter.OAuthSignpostClient
  at com.wirelessdesigns.android.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:37)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm trying to figure out what may have changed in the underlying implementation between the Android versions that would affect this and what the workaround might be?  [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306792/android-jtwitter-oauthsignpostclient) was answered a while back, but the answer was in the form of a now-dead link to a forum post.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Clearly OAuthSignpostClient is implemented using an API introduced in level 5 or later. You should apparently be able to extract OAuthSignpostClient.java from jtwitter.jar to find out exactly what that is. I tried to do that just now but my JDK appears to be broken. <sigh>

Comment: Can you post the stuff that appears in logcat just above the exception?  Should be a few lines with "VFY" in them that will tell you exactly where the problem is (in a perhaps cryptic way).  Note also that the verifier works differently in 2.0+; pre-2.0 it rejected classes immediately if anything looked wrong, 2.0 and later it logs a warning and inserts an "always throw" instruction that fires when the code executes.  More info: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/verifier.html;hb=HEAD .

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I ended up doing a workaround to handle this issue, but I'm still interested in why it did this and if there was a better workaround.  I updated the stack trace in the post to include the logcat output from just before.  It's looking for a reference to a Swing class (which Android obviously doesn't have), but I never called the askUser() method either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Android 2.0, the verifier would immediately reject classes when something wasn't right.  In 2.0 and later, reporting of certain failures is deferred until the code is actually executed.  Attempting to call a nonexistent or inaccessible method is one such case.

This is an example of why the verifier behavior was changed.  Even though you're not calling the absent function, the whole class that's trying to call it is getting rejected.

Some workarounds can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html), but it sounds like you've found one on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  Our workaround was to drop support for 1.5/1.6 (annoying).  However, just recently I've engaged the developer of JTwitter to help decouple Swing from his library, thanks to your direction on finding the error.  Cheers!

Comment: ...and indeed Swing is now decoupled from JTwitter. Sorry for the trouble it caused.